# how to access the phone call state in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to know whether the call is disconnected or continued, and based on that I want to perform an action in the application.

Can anyone tell me how to check if the phone call is disconnected or not?
along with that I also want to know if it is received by the end-user or not

any kind of help will be appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answer which he uses a deprecated package you can use this package instead which will work fine [phone_state](https://pub.dev/packages/phone_state)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take the steps I list below:

1. One line of code can make a phone call
2. Wait for any in-flight phone
3. Calls Watch everything that happens on the phone during a single Call or all
   calls.
4. Keep track of the length of calls, errors, and
   call drops.

Now let’s start

**Install the plugin**

Flutter_phone_state: ^0.5.8

**Initiate a call**

It is best to make calls from your app whenever you can. This is the best way to find where the call came from.

final phoneCall = FlutterPhoneState.makePhoneCall("480-555-1234");

The truth about a call comes from a PhoneCall object.

```
showCallInfo(PhoneCall phoneCall) {
    print(phoneCall.status);
    print(phoneCall.isComplete);
    print(phoneCall.events);
}
```

PhoneCall.events can be read as a stream, and when the call is over, the plugin will gracefully close the stream. The plugin keeps an eye on all calls in progress and will eventually force any call to time out.

```
watchEvents(PhoneCall phoneCall) {
  phoneCall.eventStream.forEach((PhoneCallEvent event) {
    print("Event $event");
  });
  print("Call is complete");
}
```

You could also just wait until the call is over.

```
waitForCompletion(PhoneCall phoneCall) async {
  await phoneCall.done;
  print("Call is completed");
}
```

**Accessing in-flight calls**

In-flight calls can be accessed like this:

```
final `activeCalls = FutterPhoneState.activeCalls;`
```

Note that activeCalls is a copy of the calls at the time you called it. This copy cannot be changed. It won't be updated on its own.
Watching all events

You can watch all the events instead of just focusing on one call. We recommend using “FlutterPhoneState.phoneCallEventStream” because it includes our own tracking logic, call timeouts, failures, etc.

```
watchAllPhoneCallEvents() {
  FlutterPhoneState.phoneCallEvents.forEach((PhoneCallEvent event) {
    final phoneCall = event.call;
    print("Got an event $event");
  });
  print("That loop ^^ won't end");
}
```

You can sign up to get the raw events if you want to. Keep in mind that there are only so many of these events.

```
watchAllRawEvents() {
  FlutterPhoneState.rawPhoneEvent.forEach((RawPhoneEvent event) {
    final phoneCall = event.call;
    print("Got an event $event");
  });
  print("That loop ^^ won't end");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this package is deprecated and is not maintained for the last 2 years. That's the reason I wanted an alternative to this.

Answer (score 0):

use phone_state_background. is gives phone call state callback in background so you have to write own code for that part.